# Remove dropdown arrow from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I want to remove dropdown arrow which is created by `AutoCompleteTextView` when I use `TextInputLayout` and use Style: `ExposedDropdownMenu`

[image: Added image about what I want to remove]

Below is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:hint="Marital Status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edt_marital" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: It's AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @pskink Please read my code too, AutoCompletetextview is acting the same here, the same design. Have a look here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you would like to avoid the dropdown icon just use the **`app:endIconMode`** attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
      app:endIconMode="none"
      ...>
```

Before and after:

[image][image]

Comment: After setting app:endIconMode="none", dropdown menu is not showing

Comment: @Shams u got a solution for it?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti any idea why the menu would not show up if the arrow disappears?

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys, after having searched a lot and found little. I was trying to achieve how I wanted and I wanted to share the experience and result with you.
As the same [Material Design](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#implementing-an-exposed-dropdown-menu) documentation says.

A result [Image Dropdown Menu](https://i.postimg.cc/250nYJzq/image1.png) similar to a Spinner, following the documentation. Next code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/styleFilterLabelLatoRegular"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtAssignedTo"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineBegin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSearchQuestionnaire">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/actvTypesAnswer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:hint="@string/text_answer" />
```

Now a result as expected from an AutoCompleteTextView [Image AutoCompleteTextView](https://i.postimg.cc/ZYxJgk4Z/image2.png). Code xml.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txtSearchQuestionnaire"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_15dp"
                app:endIconMode="none"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/styleFilterLabelLatoRegular"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineEnd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideLineBegin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPeriodActivation">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/actvNameQuestionnaire"
                    style="@style/textAppearanceSettingInputEdittextFilter.Enabled"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:hint="@string/text_search_name_questionnaire" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The only changes were to add the attribute `app: endIconMode = "none"` in TextInputLayout and in the AutoCompleteTextView the attribute `android: drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"`

Excuse my level of English!!

Answer (score 0):

Besides doing this in your layout.xml there is also the opportunity to do it programmatically. Therefor you need an instance of the surrounding `TextInputLayout` instead of the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

To remove the drop down button, just run

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE);
```

To activate the drop down button, just run

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_DROPDOWN_MENU);
```